# Raycast not hitting primitive geometry meshes

Tags: typescript, three.js

I am trying use a ray to hover over objects with the mouse, but only meshes loaded from 3D asset files are being hit by it. Any meshes created from primitive geometry like `CylinderGeometry` or `BoxGeometry` are being ignored.

The object I am trying to hit is `CameraPole`, which is a class that extends `THREE.Group` and contains the `pole` mesh.

```
export default class CameraPole extends Group {
    public pole: Mesh;
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.name = 'CameraPole';

        this.pole = new Mesh(
            new CylinderGeometry(.25, .25, 5, 32),
            new MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xffffff})
        );

        this.position.x = -34;
        this.position.y = 5;
        this.position.z = 17.8;

        this.add(this.pole);
    }
}
```

This is just one example, but there are other primitive objects in my scene and none of them are getting detected by the raycast.

I construct and add it to the scene:

```
const cameraPole = new CameraPole();
scene.add(cameraPole);
```

But when I try to detect it with a raycast hit, I am only hitting objects that were loaded from 3D asset files. The returned array never contains any objects generated from primitive geometry.

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const mouse = {
        x: (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1,
        y: (e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 - 1
    };
    const ray = new Raycaster();
    ray.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    console.log(ray.intersectObjects(scene.children, true)); // Only returning complex meshes, not geometric objects created dynamically.
});
```

I've also tried looking specifically for the camera pole but with this I still get nothing:

```
ray.intersectObject(cameraPole, true);
```

Edit: If it's relevant, the camera is an `OrthographicCamera`.

Edit 2: So I figured out that if I don't change the position of `CameraPole` it works fine. When the position is updated it is no longer detected by the raycast. Any word on how to fix this?

Comment: My first guess is that the raycaster is having a hard time traversing through your custom `CameraPole` class. Does the cylinder show up in the render at all? What do you get when you do `scene.traverse((obj) => {console.log(obj);})`? Does it output your `pole` cylinder?

Comment: @Marquizzo Yes I am seeing the "CameraPole" object in the `traverse`, I can see the cylinder in the scene, and I am most certainly mousing over it. Other objects are selected at the correct positions just fine. This cylinder is not the only object either. I also have a cube created from `BoxGeometry` (created using the exact same pattern as the CameraPole) which is also not being picked up.

Comment: Could it be your inverted `mouse.y` value? The [raycaster example](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster) suggests you use `y: - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;` but you're doing `y: ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 - 1;`

Comment: @Marquizzo Huh, didn't even notice it was inverted in the example. However after doing that nothing is getting detected at all.

Comment: @Marquizzo I should also add that I am using an `OrthographicCamera`, If that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure why it's not working. Maybe because you're changing the position of the Group with `this.position.x...` instead of the position of the Mesh with `this.pole.position.x...`? I'm starting to grasp at straws here, I'd probably need to see a live example [in a code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to really get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @Marquizzo I was afraid someone would say that lol. It will take me some time to pull out the relevant components for an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202675/discussion-between-marquizzo-and-chrispytoes).